# AOSP - Can't access FWK-Only library from vendor module

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, android-source, vendor

I need to access a FWK-Only library (libaaudio) from vendor module. Is there any possibility to do it via VNDK or VNDK-SP ? If so, Can you give an idea how to achieve it. Thanks.

When I tried to access libaaudio from vendor, I got the error that

```
Library (libaaudio.so) needed or dlopened by "/vendor/lib64/lib module@1.0" is not accessible for the namespaces: [name="(default)", ld_library_paths="", default_library_paths="/vendor/lib64:/vendor/lib64/hw:/vendor/lib64/egl", permitted_paths="odm:/vendor:/system/vendor"]
```

Comment: Didn't your vendor provide any setup instructions?

Comment: No instructions found regarding this functionality.  I found this document from google and trying to do it. https://source.android.com/docs/core/architecture/images/VNDK.pdf . but  It's not enough to implement it. 

I need to know whether it is possible to access a FWK-Only library from vendor module or not atleast.